# Module dependency has friend dependency on org.netbeans.libs.javacimpl/1but is not listed as friend

Tags: netbeans, maven, netbeans-platform

I am developing some application on NetBeans Platform 6.9.1 with Maven. I have Netbeans Platform Application created from maven artefact. I need to depend on Java Source API, because my application is performing some kind of analysis on the source code of Java projects.

I have followed partially this tutorial: http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/60/nbm-copyfqn.html (with the exception, that I tried to do dependency management with Maven).

When I try to satisfy all dependencies (add them to pom.xml), I get this message:

Module dependency has friend dependency on org.netbeans.libs.javacimpl/1but is not listed as friend.

For javacimpl package (it's requested by the application that starts up)... the same error it writes for another two packages...

I have read many discussions in other forums, but none of them gave me clear solution.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your module.xml you have to define an impl dependency

Have a look at the [codehause page](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nbm-maven-plugin/nbm.html#class_dependency) It would be better if you could use a spec dependency, but I have a feeling you wont be able to.

As an example your module.xml will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nbm>
    <licenseName>Apache License, Version 2.0</licenseName>
    <licenseFile>license.txt</licenseFile>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <id>org.netbeans.api:org-netbeans-modules-java-source</id>
            <type>impl</type>
            <explicitValue>0.60.2.10.8.4</explicitValue>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</nbm>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The way with Maven seemed to be pretty difficult - the NBP is not ready to work out of the box with maven. So I finally decided to develop my application as standard NetBeans project. Thanks for your time!